# Clickable Svg inline with html not working in Safari but standalone works

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have uploaded a file which carries the functionality I'm trying for in a simple format. It works fine as a stand-alone svg in the five modern Windows browsers. When wrapped in HTML it stops working in Safari, but still fine in the other four.
I would like to know why, if [THIS](http://www.equabass.co.uk/test/Tshirt.svg) works in Safari, why doesn't 
[THIS, wrapped in HTML](http://www.equabass.co.uk/test/Tshirt.html) work in Safari?
I've tried to re-use snippets from my other pages which I know are good; I'm stumped, hoping it's something silly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems in order of silliness...no wonder I was struggling.

1/ Javascript moved out of svg to bottom of html .

Now the image appears in Safari. My thanks to the red smiley face svg which showed this layout; unfortunately I've lost the link to it.

2/ Firebug says remove the "CDATA" brackets; this step restores the "onclick" function for the svg element.

Solution [HERE](http://www.equabass.co.uk/test/CleanTshirt.svg).